# Outlier detection in high-dimensional longitudinal data

Tags: panel-data, outliers, distance, anomaly-detection

I'm having a longitudinal dataset with a large number of variables where I would like to use a ML algorithm to inspect possible outliers. What are the techniques you would use for this? I've seen a similar post on using Mahalanobis distance versus other techniques which are more robust to an increasing number of variables, but my difficulty lies in the fact on how to handle the longitudinal aspect in such an analysis. Any thoughts? :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04236) article? I have never worked with time series before so I'm no expert at all, but I came across this some time ago. Another method that seems reasonable is the [isolation forest](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-anomaly-detection-with-real-world-data-984c12a71acb), maybe give it a look. Hope it helped!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I've read through it. I've also looked at Isolation Forest indeed and I'm think of adapting it somehow to incorporate the longitudinal aspect of the data;

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I've read through it, but longitudinal is not necessarily multivariate time series as the length and timestamps of each individual can differ. I've also looked at Isolation Forest indeed and I'm thinking of adapting it somehow to incorporate the longitudinal aspect of the data. The main issue I see currently is to address the similarity of two individuals that have different time lengths in the data..

Comment: I've found the package kml in R, which is doing clustering of longitudinal data. Perhaps I can use something like this; i.e. using clustering for outlier detection similarly as DBScan is often used for that..